# R table with missing data

Tags: r, count, missing-data

I would like to create a table that gets the labels (for rows and columns) form one source and the data from another source.

I have the following data:

```
var1_labels = c('A', 'B', 'C')
var2_labels = c(1, 2, 3)
var1_data = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
var2_data = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

now I would like to create a table with the count of each element, so I run:

```
table(var1_data, var2_data)
```

and I get:

> ```
>            var2_data
> var1_data  1  2
>         A  5  0
>         C  4 11
> ```

But what I want to get is:

> ```
>            var2_data
> var1_data  1  2  3
>         A  5  0  0
>         B  0  0  0
>         C  4 11  0
> ```

what is the simplest way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using *factors*, with specific levels:

```
var1_data <- factor(var1_data, levels = var1_labels)
var2_data <- factor(var2_data, levels = var2_labels)
table(var1_data, var2_data)
```

result:

```
         var2_data
var1_data  1  2  3
        A  5  0  0
        B  0  0  0
        C  4 11  0
```